# Best format for JSON encoding?

Tags: php, android, json

I'm not familiar with PHP and JSON but need it for my Android project.

I'm confused about which JSON format is the **most effective**. Most examples I saw use *Associative* array by using this code:

```
$result = mysql_query($queryString)
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json['contact']['ID'] = $row['ID'];
    $json['contact']['Name'] = $row['Name'];
}
```

**Format #1**

```
{"contact":{"ID":"1","Name":"Andy"}}
```

I like that format but I don't know how to make each key hold more than one value. So when my query returns *Andy* and *Bob*, the json will only contains *Bob*.

Then, I found this PHP code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $json['contact'][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

It makes the json looks like this:

**Format #2**

```
{"contact":[["1","Andy"],["2","Bob"]]}
```

But in Android, there is no `JSONObject` method to `getArray()`. Even if there is, I want to avoid using *numbered* array that requires `[0]` or `[1]` to be called.

So, which one is better? Or any other alternative?

Thanks

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: @Charles Thanks, can `mysqli_result::fetch_array` take the same parameters as `mysql_fetch_array`? I'm very new to PHP so I don't quite understand the docs

Comment: Same params, different order -- the connection *always* comes first in `mysqli_`.  If you're going to go with mysqli instead of PDO, be sure to read the [documentation on mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements).  They're more painful to use than those in PDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that one method is more "effective" than the other, they serve different purposes. One is an associative object, and the other is a indexed array.

In your case, it looks like you want a list (indexed array) of objects. So what i would recommend doing is:

```
$result = mysql_query($queryString)
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $json['contact'][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

which would result in the json:

```
{"contact":[{"ID":"1","Name":"Andy"}, {"ID":"2","Name":"Bob"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But in Android, do I use the `getJSONArray()` instead of `getJSONObject()` method to read it? Thanks

Comment: I haven't worked with android before, but my guess would be you call `JSONArray people = (new JSONObject(json_str)).getJSONArray("contact")` and then iterate over that in a loop calling `people.getJSONObject(i)`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use mysql_fetch_array(); ?

Comment: I tried using `mysql_fetch_array()` but it returns the same row twice. So it gives me `{"contact":[["1","Andy"],["1","Andy"]]}`

Comment: Just realized I used `mysql_fetch_array()` the wrong way. I followed supericy answer and it works

Answer (score 1):

```
{"contacts":[{"id":1,"name":"Alice"},{"id":2,"name":"Bob"}]}
```

An object with key contacts that contain an array of contact objects perhaps?

Comment: Didn't know we can do that. I followed supericy code and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it hardcoded (not as nice as mysql_fetch_array() tho.);

```
$result = array();
$i = 0;
while(...) {
  $result[] .= '{"id":"'.$i.'","name":"'.$fetch['name'].'"}';
  $i++;
}
echo "[".implode(',', $result)."]";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I will use supericy code since it works and looks cleaner